# Actionscript 3 read specific info from XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on something here and I want to read specific from my XML.
I want the program to find the info about a id if for example  check.text = 123.
(123 is the id). 
So when I write an id, the info about that id will be traced.

Now my code just displays the name. im stuck here.. please help me!

my xml:

```
<123>
     <name>Cola</name>
     <price>20</price>
</123>
```

as3 code:

```
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.net.URLLoader; 

var myXML:XML = new XML(); 
var XML_URL:String = "test.xml"; 
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); 

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data); 
    trace("Data loaded."); 
    trace(myXML.name);
}
```

Comment: Element names must start with a letter or underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML should looks like:

```
<data>
    <item id="123">
        <name>Cola</name>
        <price>20</price>
    </item>
    <item id="456">
        <name>Cola</name>
        <price>20</price>
    </item>
</data>
```

This

```
your_loaded_xml.item.(@id==123)
```

returns

```
<item id="123">
    <name>Cola</name>
    <price>20</price>
</item>
```

so you can get the name and price:

```
your_loaded_xml.item.(@id==123).name
your_loaded_xml.item.(@id==123).price
```

Comment: But if i want to set the id i search for to check.text, how can i do it?
your_loaded_xml.item.(@id== check.text) dosen´t work...

Comment: Can you provide FLA and XML file? It should work. I checked. Works with input text. [Code](http://subdan.ru/work/scr.png) & [Result](http://subdan.ru/work/res.png)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i cant get it to work...

I use this code, and nothing happens.. I use exactly the same code as you...

Comment: Error appears? What will be in output after `trace(result);`?

Comment: I don't know how to help you. Sorry.